# Calculating the integral with x and x' (discretization) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, discretization, chord

I am currently trying to calculate the velocity distribution over an airfoil for a problem at work and am stuck on how to properly type this into Matlab. I know that x′ is a dummy chordwise coordinate I should use in the integral to distinguish it from x, but am confused how to relay that to Matlab. How do I distinguish x' from x and then sum up all those values to get the full velocity distribution over the chord in Matlab?

My coworker recommends using traps, but I am unsure how to work with x'. T

```
Vt = zeros(length(XC), 1); % XC corresponds to the x value used to calculate dT/dxfor i = 1:length(XC)        
Prime = XC(i);      % x'
    dT = dT(i);   % dT/dx'
    X = XC;         
    X(X==XPrime) = 0; % remove the x = x' singularity to allow proper integration
    int_expression = (1/2*pi)*dT*(X-XPrime);
Vt(i) =-trapz(X, int_expression); 
end
```

The integral is in the link and simple, with dT/dx posted as a photo as well. dT/dx that plugs into the equation that is being integrated

[image: The equation that needs to be integrated]

[image: dT/dx that plugs into the equation that is being integrated]

Comment: Is dT/dx a function of x or x'?

Comment: This looks like an integral equation where the outcome is tangential velocity as a function of x.  You're integrating w.r.t. x' here.  Since dT/dx is a sum of five different terms, I'd recommend that you treat each one individually.  That last one is special.  You'll have a singularity at x = 0.  What do you plan to do about that?  What is its physical significance?

Comment: I'm guessing that x = 0 is the leading edge of your airfoil.  The flow splits at that point into the upper and lower contour. That would be the source of your singularity, true?